# laravel 5.7 spatie/permission how to do relation between User class and Role class

Tags: php, laravel

I use spatie and want to find out if in class a User needs to do relations for the Role class.

Maybe you could give an example of how to have the tables filled in the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Check Spatie/laravel-permission documentation carefully: [here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#using-permissions-via-roles)

After creating a user in Laravel, let assume `$user` is an object of `User` class then you can simply make a relation with roles table by calling `assignRole` method

`$user->assignRole('writer');`

// You can also assign multiple roles at once

`$user->assignRole('writer', 'admin');`

// or as an array
`$user->assignRole(['writer', 'admin']);`